# Body of Request in express bodyParse coming up as "{}", even though jQuery is sending data

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm creating an application, and I want to make an ajax request. I have node.js with express and bodyparse on the server-side, and jQuery on the client side:

```js
$.ajax({
url: "/sign-up",
type: "POST",
data: {
test: "Hello"
},
complete() {
console.log('process complete');
},
success(data) {
console.log(data);
console.log('process sucess');
},
error() {
console.log('process error');
}
});
```

As you can see, I'm sending data over AJAX with jQuery. Now, on the server side, I have:

```js
app.post("/sign-up", (req, res) => {
    console.log("THE POST HAPPENED!", req.body.test);
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

However, req.body is `{}`, and does not contain my data.
And I'm using body parse middleware:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Why isn't the request body containing the data I posted?

To help, here are my request and response headers: 
Request Headers: 
Accept: */* 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9 
Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Length: 10 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 
Cookie: io=yiZgsQLgJQcZnu4rAAAF 
Host: localhost:3000 
Origin: http://localhost:3000 
Referer: http://localhost:3000/?username=N8User&user-type=Student
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Mobile Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest 
Response Headers: 
Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Length: 2 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2019 22:26:04 GMT 
ETag: W/"2-vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8" 
X-Powered-By: Express

Comment: Can you paste your request and response headers

Comment: That body is urlencoded, not JSON. The `bodyParser.json()` isn't going to touch it. Use [the proper decoder](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed the bug!